# How to assign the jQuery variable value to ruby instance variable in script

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I have a script like this i added in one of the pdf html view

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
     var header_height = $("#custom_header").height();
     <% @height %> = header_height
  });
</script>
```

here i need to assign the header_height value to @height But it is not working with above script and i need to access that variable outside the script so can anyone help me out

Comment: The jquery won't run until the page has been loaded on the client's computer, well after the ruby code has been interpreted and run on the server.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i need to add that @height value to pdf header height in styles like

Comment: <style> #custom_header { height: <%= @height %>  }  </style>

Comment: You want to get the height of the element rendered on the client's computer, so that you can set the height of the element in your rendered pdf, is that right?  I would highly suggest that you just choose a height that works best for the pdf page as it has nothing to do with how your client's computer renders it.  The only other way, is to send the `header_height` (and any other value you want to render the page) in a separate http call